# Jquery get nth-child having a particular class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a html table as follows

```
<table id = "table1">
<tr>
    <td class="take">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="take">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="take">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="take">11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td class="take">14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td class="take">16</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get a jquery selector which gets me the second `td` having class of `take` in the first `tr` of table. :) funny huh? But it pains.

I tried below.

```
$("#table1").find('tr:first-child td.take:nth-child(2)').text()
```

But no use.

EDIT: I want `td` having text 4 not 2

I made a fiddle to play around.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xdg36v2p/1/)

Comment: in your html second `td` in first `tr` does not have class `take`

Comment: You are right.  I want td having text 4 not 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:first`to target first row `tr` along with `:eq' selector with index 1 to target 2nd td element in it:

```
$("#table1").find('tr:first td.take:eq(1)').text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1vzvcr0o/)**

Comment: I want td having text 4 not 2

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to get a jquery selector which gets me the second td having class of take in the first tr of table

```
$("#table1 tr:first td.take:eq(1)").text()
```

Or,

```
$('#table1').find('tr:first td.take:eq(1)').text()
```

Comment: I want td having text 4 not 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can iterate all `td`s with `class="take"` in first row of table and then check it's index eqaul to 1 (as index is 0 based, second element will have index =1).

```
$("#table1").find('tr:first-child td.take').each(function(index){

  if(index==1)
    alert("Text is "+$(this).text());
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xdg36v2p/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#table1").find("tr td.take:eq(1)").text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xdg36v2p/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use direclly,using **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** selector

```
$("#table1 td.take:eq(1)").text();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhewxedr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
//alert("hello");
var tableRows = $("#table1").find("tr"); //fetching all rows of the tbody
//(tableRows);
$.each(tableRows, function(index, value) { //iterating all fetched rows
    //alert("hello");
    var tdValue = $(value).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
    $(value).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass("addclass");
});
```

```css
.addclass {
  background: red;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="take">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="take">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="take">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="take">11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td class="take">14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td class="take">16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
var tableRows = $("#table1").find("tr"); //fetching all rows of the tbody
$.each(tableRows, function( index, value ) { //iterating all fetched rows
    var tdValue=$(value).find("td:nth-child(3)").html(); //can set which column required
    $(value).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass("adding"); //can set anything
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain and edit the format of your code.

Comment: ok sir now you can set or get or change your tr,td according to you